# Is there a way to create a matrix in R only when condition is met?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I've found the function to use to find the information needed but matrix is too large.

I've a restaurants dataset and I want to determine whether restaurants are in the proximity of each other by using longitude and latitude. I have been using the function distHaversine, which allows to measure distance and works perfectly with smaller subsets:

```
rest_m <- cbind(restaurants$longitude, restaurants$latitude)
distance_m <- distm(rest_m, rest_m, fun = distHaversine)
```

Only issue is that the dataset is 55k rows and the matrix is way too large to be used.

I am thinking now to reduce the list of restaurants and calculate distance only for businesses that are in the same State. There is a column State in the dataset.
Is there a way to create the matrix only when this condition (restaurants are in the same state) is met?

Thank you!

```
rest_m <- cbind(restaurants$longitude, restaurants$latitude)
distance_m <- distm(rest_m, rest_m, fun = distHaversine)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Perhaps you need to do a group by 'State' or split by 'State', `lst1 <- split(restaurants[c("longitude", "latitude"), restaurants$State); lapply(lst1, function(x) distm(as.matrix(x), fun = distHaversine))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have to find restaurants in proximity of one another. You would be better off using something like k-means clustering on the longitude and latitude columns with Euclidean distance (Restaurants in the same cluster would then be close to one another) . Using distHaversine is an overkill for your problem statement.